# Does 来 mean "bring"?

Tags: vocabulary

In the sentence "来一瓶啤酒", what does the word "来" mean?
I guess, it means "to bring". But I couldn't find this meaning for the word "来" in the MDBG dictionary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

来 can be used to replace actual verb in spoken. E.g.  来一首歌(唱一首歌)，来瓶啤酒(拿瓶啤酒).

This use of 来 can be found in dictionaries.

Answer (score 8):

来 come --> deliver --> serve --> bring

来一瓶啤酒 (come --> deliver --> serve --> bring me a bottle of beer)

The subject in 来一瓶啤酒 is the person listening to this order (e.g. waiter) and the verb 来 (come) is basically a short version of 送過來

(送過)來一瓶啤酒 = 送一瓶啤酒過來 - deliver/ bring me a bottle of beer

'来' still means 'come', but it can be extended to 'deliver' and from 'deliver' extend to 'bring'

Similarly: 上 (forward) --> deliver --> serve -->bring

e.g. 再上主菜 (then bring me the main course)